# How to trigger an action only after receiving two or more events in an event driven architecture?

Tags: architecture, microservices, event-driven-design

I have started implementing microservices in an Event-Driven Architecture. Therefore some of my services are publishing events and listening to some other events. It is very straightforward to implement a listener when an action depends on one single event, for example;

```
ORDER SERVICE 
  1. Publishes `ORDER_INTENT_EVENT` then
  2. Listens for `CREDIT_AVAILABLE_EVENT` then
  3. Finishes the `Order`

CREDIT SERVICE
  1. Listens for `ORDER_INTENT_EVENT` then
  2. Verifies if the client has credit then locks the amount and
  3. Publishes `CREDIT_AVAILABLE_EVENT`
```

The problem arises when OrderService has to wait for more than one event, for example;

```
ORDER SERVICE 
  1. Publishes `ORDER_INTENT_EVENT` then
  2. Listens for `CREDIT_AVAILABLE_EVENT` 
             and `INVENTORY_AVAILABLE_EVENT` then <--- Problem here

  3. Finishes the `Order`

CREDIT SERVICE
  1. Listens for `ORDER_INTENT_EVENT` then
  2. Verifies if the client has credit then locks the amount and
  3. Publishes `CREDIT_AVAILABLE_EVENT`

INVENTORY SERVICE
  1. Listens for `ORDER_INTENT_EVENT` then
  2. Verifies if inventory has items then locks the items and
  3. Publishes `INVENTORY_AVAILABLE_EVENT`
```

The thing is; I am pooling both queues `CREDIT_AVAILABLE_QUEUE` and `INVENTORY_AVAILABLE_QUEUE`,
and both events has to be present so I can finish an order. **How can I coordinate so that OrderService sees both events as only one?**

I can implement it at the application level, for example; if one event arises I save it to the database and check if there is the other corresponding event to same order, if so I proceed with finishing the order, if not I do nothing then when the other event arrives I will have both of them so I am able to finish the order. The problem with this approach is that there is a minimal chance of receiving both events at the same time generating race conditions.

What is the suggested pattern for this kind of scenario?

*PS.: I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509121/listening-on-multiple-events) but one answer suggests .net related tools and the other points to a third party service. I am interested in a pattern/code solution.*

Comment: This is known as Complex Event Processing (CEP) and there are many frameworks in open source world to solve this type of problems.

Comment: Yes, @skjagini the thing is that I was looking for a pattern to handle this scenario and implement it my self. I actually already have an answer. Will post it as soon as I understand things more clearly.

Comment: @RenatoGama What was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have multiple input sources to a particular piece of state, you have the potential for a race condition.  This is why we have locks.  You MUST use a lock of some sort to handle the race condition.

This may be implemented at the database layer, or using a locking library, or a shared piece of memory (please use a locking library unless you have way more understanding of memory / CPU architecture than this posting implies).

Most languages implement some form of mutex locking to allow this problem to be solved.  If you are using multiple processes / machines / etc, you will need some form of external mutex locking (often implemented by your database provider).  If you lack this, there are distributed lock systems that also can be used.